# system() command not working C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell, stl

I'm writing a program in C++ as a GUI to the dvd drives in linux. To enumerate the drives I used the following code:

```
std::string filnam = "donotdelete.dlt";
std::stringstream cmd;
cmd << "> " << filnam;  //create new file or empty file if already exists
system(cmd.str().c_str());
int NUMDRIVES = 4; //on my system the number of DVD/BluRay drives

for(int i=0; i<NUMDRIVES; ++i) {
    std::string left = "\"echo $(blkid /dev/sr", middle = " | awk -F '\"' '{print $2}' 2>&1) >> ";
    cmd.str("");
    cmd << "echo " << i << ">> " << filnam;
    std::system(cmd.str().c_str());
    cmd <<left<<i<<middle<<filnam<<"\"";
    std::system(cmd.str().c_str());
}
```

The UNIX commands are blkid to get information about a cd/dvd/bluray with awk to extract the name of the disc in the drive and then write the names of the discs to a file. Basically the file never gets created nor is it written to. If I copy the command exactly as it appears in the wxMessageBox and paste it into terminal the command executes as expected. Can someone please explain why it's not working in the C++ code above?
Please don't tell me that I should write the file using C++ because I need to use the shell for other commands in this program, and please don't suggest another language other than C++.  I've included  and . Also, I've tried using pipes but I need the command to finish executing before I move to the next step in my code.  Thank you, in advance.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What happens? Errors?

Comment: Print the command before executing it, eyeball it to see it's what you expected. In particular, you are not clearing the stream between two `system` calls in the loop - did you mean to append the second command to the end of the first?

Comment: System runs the bourne shell `sh`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html You're using `bash` conventions. I don't know if `sh` is an alias for `bash` on linux. But if not, that could be the problem.

Comment: "not working" - the file is never created nor appended; I've tried outputting the command text using wxMessageBox and the text seems to be correct; I'm not quite sure how to test if it works in sh as well as bash but I'll look into that

Comment: First check whether sh is just a link to bash: `ls -l \`which sh\`` . I found one article that says in Ubuntu it's a link to `dash`.

Comment: To test the code I wrote it in a shell script starting first with #!/bin/bash and then with #!/bin/sh and the code didn't work when using the sh shell. The sh shell did provide output, however, and running that script using the system() function still didn't create nor append the file.

Comment: and, on my system it's dash

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling /bin/bash in my system() function and the bash specific code seemed to work.